# scala: How to get the class in its own constructor

Tags: scala, constructor

I need access to the Class of the object being constructed in its own constructor (for various detailed reasons I don't think are relevant to my question).

I want something like this

```
class Foo(val i:Int)
class Bar extends Foo(this.getClass.getName.length)
val b = new Bar
println(b.i)
```

to print 3 ("Bar".length).  But it doesn't.  If the code above is inside some other object, "this" refers to that object.  If the code above is not inside some other object (just in some package), the compiler complains with

```
error: this can be used only in a class, object, or template
class Bar extends Foo(this.getClass.getName)
                      ^
```

CLARIFICATION: I can't change Foo to use a val in its body instead of its constructor because Foo's API already exists and is fixed (so, yes, *i* must be a constructor parameter).  It needs an integer argument at constructor time, but that integer can only be calculated with access to the Class.

(I know the example above is still silly and degenerate.  If people care, I can explain in detail why I need the class in my real project, http://code.google.com/p/factorie)

Surely, the class of the object being constructed is known to the compiler and runtime during construction.  With what syntax can I get it?  (Is there no such syntax?  If not, I wonder why.  I'm surprised it there doesn't seem to be a simple, standard way to get this.)

Comment: This is my first question posted to StackOverflow.  It is incredibly lovely to get answers so quickly.  Thank you all.  I see now, however, that I will have to make my example more complicated to better reflect my true use-case.  I think the think to do now is edit my question.  I'll do that now.

Comment: Do you realize that access to a public `val` is still mediated by a (regular polymorphic) method?

Comment: @chrispy: Thanks for the suggestion, but Geoff Reedy's answer does the trick to both the original question and the slightly edited one.  His answer is now accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to explain your motivation for wanting to do this. Does name have to be a constructor parameter of `Foo` or can it be an abstract member? Does it have to be a `val` or will a `def` do.

You can do this

```
class Foo(val name: String)
class Bar extends Foo("") {
  override val name = getClass.getName
}
```

and `new Bar().name` will give Bar

But I suspect that if your true motivation is known then there is a better way to do what you really want.

Comment: Geoff,  Thank you.  This does the trick.  It preserves the original API of Foo, while allowing initialization of the val using this.getClass.  I imagine that Bar takes the same amount of memory as Foo, but I'm not sure, and I don't know how to verify this.

Comment: @mccallum you can use `javap -p classname` to show the fields that are in the classes. In this case, there will be a field for the value in both Foo and Bar, so there is extra storage. If the constructor parameter for Foo is an object, it'd be best to use null as the argument to minimize the storage requirements.

Answer (score 8):

A lazy val solves this problem:

```
object Early
{
    abstract class Foo { val name: String }

    class Bar extends Foo { lazy val name = getClass.getName }

    def
    main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val b = new Bar
        println(b.name)
    }
}
```

Yields:

```
% scala Early
Early$Bar
```

Comment: By the way, the name `Early` is a leftover from my first attempt to solve this problem by using the "early definition" construct.

Comment: Randal, Thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately it doesn't do the trick for me, as now better described in my edited question.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether this is possible in a clean way. If you like hacks you could do

```
class Bar extends Foo((new Exception).getStackTrace.apply(0).getClassName)
```

However I **strongly** advertise against it!

Answer (score 2):

This appears to satisfy your requirement without using a lazy val and without altering the base class:

```
scala> class Base(val name: String)
defined class Base

scala> class Derived extends Base(classOf[Derived].getName)
defined class Derived

scala> new Derived name
res0: String = Derived
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

class Bar extends Foo(classOf[Bar].getName.length)

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
  class Foo(otherName: Option[String] = None) {
    val name = otherName.getOrElse(this.getClass.getName)
  }
  class Bar extends Foo()
  val b = new Bar
  println(b.name)
```